# Unlist mixed Dataframe into Rows. R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Been rummaging through previously answered questions, but can't find one in-line with what I'm trying to do.

Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
Names = c("Andy", "Bill", "Carl", "Dave")
Letters = c("A", list(c("A", "B", "C")), list(c("B", "C")), "B")
DATA = as.data.frame(cbind(Names, Letters))
```

Here is a simplified version of what I want:

```
Names2 = c("Andy", rep("Bill", 3), rep("Carl", 2), "Dave")
Letters2 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B")
DATA2 = as.data.frame(cbind(Names2, Letters2))
```

I'm sure this is simple, but it's been doing my head in.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tidyr` function [unnest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.1/topics/unnest) can help you here.
The only problem you have is that your `DATA` frame contains a vector-of-lists in each column. If we convert the Names column to a character vector first you can unnest the Letters lists:

```
Names <- c("Andy", "Bill", "Carl", "Dave")
Letters <- c("A", list(c("A", "B", "C")), list(c("B", "C")), "B")
DATA <- as.data.frame(cbind(Names, Letters))

DATA
  Names Letters
1  Andy       A
2  Bill A, B, C
3  Carl    B, C
4  Dave       B

str(DATA)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Names  :List of 4
  ..$ : chr "Andy"
  ..$ : chr "Bill"
  ..$ : chr "Carl"
  ..$ : chr "Dave"
 $ Letters:List of 4
  ..$ : chr "A"
  ..$ : chr  "A" "B" "C"
  ..$ : chr  "B" "C"
  ..$ : chr "B"
```

So we convert the Names

```
DATA %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Names = unlist(Names)) %>%
  unnest()

  Names Letters
1  Andy       A
2  Bill       A
3  Bill       B
4  Bill       C
5  Carl       B
6  Carl       C
7  Dave       B
```

Comment: Thanks for that, cheers (+1). By the way, just out of curiosity, I know that unnest acts row-wise (as requested), but what would act in a like-manner by unnesting each element into its own column? (with NAs being imputed where the lists being unpacked were of different lengths). I've had to work around this in the past, so if a simple dplyr friendly way of doing this exists it would be good to know. Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you wanting a separate column for each value? You could `tidyr::unnest` and then `tidyr::spread`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are like me and like to use the base R functionality.

```
do.call(
    rbind, c(apply(DATA, 1, function(x){cbind.data.frame(Names = x[1],Letters = unlist(x[2]))}),  make.row.names = FALSE)
)

#  Names Letters
#1  Andy       A
#2  Bill       A
#3  Bill       B
#4  Bill       C
#5  Carl       B
#6  Carl       C
#7  Dave       B
```

just as an addition using data.table.

```
data.table::setDT(DATA)[, .(Letters = unlist(Letters)), by = .(Names = unlist(Names))]

#   Names Letters
#1:  Andy       A
#2:  Bill       A
#3:  Bill       B
#4:  Bill       C
#5:  Carl       B
#6:  Carl       C
#7:  Dave       B
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another logical simple method. You should make two vectors, one for **Names** and another for **Letters**.

```
vecName=vector()
vecLetter=vector()
```

Now you should traverse all the names in **DATA** using outer loop. In the inner loop, you should separate letters and fill both(vecName and vecLetter) vectors.

```
r=1
for(i in 1:nrow(DATA))
{
  for(j in 1:length(DATA$Letters[[i]]))
  {
        vecName[r]=DATA$Names[[i]]
        vecLetter[r]=DATA$Letters[[i]][j]
        r=r+1
  }
}
```

Finaly, combine both vectors and make another data frame.

```
df=data.frame(vecName,vecLetter)
```